# jquery autocomplete with json issue

Tags: json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement auto complete when user types something in input using **jquery ui.** When user types something he should to see translation from json. But instead i got each key from JSON starting on a new `li` in my `ul` like on the image bellow:

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picshare.ru](http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/140810/gF5XdBXyXt.jpg))</sub>

I would like to have only one `li` with translations. How can i modify my code to get the expected result like on image bellow:

[image: screenshot1]

Here is jQuery code:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/search/" + request.term, function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value
                };
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
```

Here is JSON:

```
{"word":"cat","translation":"кошка","synonymous":["кот","котенок","котик"],"transcription":"kæt","examples":{"pedigreed cats":"породистые кошки","Cheshire cat":"Чеширский кот"}}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED**

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/search/" + request.term, function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
```

Comment: ... response($.map(data, function (key, value)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question you ask for translation but in the image you are printing synonymous, I will put the code for synonymous but should be the same for translation:

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON("/search/" + request.term, function (data) {
        var result = data["word"] + " - " + data["synonymous"].join(",");
        response([result]);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not swap the value and key, so the line would be:

```
response($.map(data, function (key, value)
```

Credit to MadFlow for getting this while I was typing.

Comment: i've updated my code but it doesn't work and any errors in console, please see my edited code up there ^